# \c_backslash_str command from l3str.sty not working (most like it's my fault...)

Tags: expl3

I don't really understand what's going on tbh. ^^ I read something about latex3 and just wanted to write \A onto the pdf with the command `\c_backslash_str` as described in the documentation, but what I get is something like "A. Anybody can explain to me why? (I use TexStudio, MikTeX, Windows 10, (re)-downloaded both programs today (03.02.2022) and updated 'all' packages on miktex, so there shouldn't be any problems in that regard.)

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{expl3}%
\begin{document}%
    \ExplSyntaxOn%
    \tl_new:c {l_my_tl}%
    \tl_set:cn {l_my_tl} {A}%
    \tl_put_left:cn {l_my_tl} { \c_backslash_str }%
    \tl_use:c {l_my_tl}%
    \ExplSyntaxOff%
\end{document}
```

Here an image of the pdf file: [image]

Comment: Use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\texttt`

Comment: ... @PhelypeOleinik seriously... I thought I loaded that (ofc not in my test document here) Thanks solved it here. Oh how embrassing (I just haven't loaded it in my tex file where I tested something with glossaries-extra) I forgot that. Tysm <3.